# Ensuring that at least one related record still exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a better way to ensure that I don't delete the last record of a relation?  I feel like this should be done through a validation, but could not make that stop the destroy action.

FYI - @organization is present because nested routes

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
....
....
  def destroy
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @location = @organization.locations.find(params[:id])
    count = Location.find_all_by_organization_id(@location.organization_id).count
    if count > 1
      @location.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed location."
      redirect_to @organization
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Could not destroy the only location."
      redirect_to @organization
    end     
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also consider the before_destroy callback (though I don't think your version is all that bad):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object

Comment: thanks for the answer.  FYI - I looked at the API for before_destroy, but could not figure out how to make it stop the destroy action.  I can leave as above, but am interested in learning more about how your suggestion could work?

Comment: Return false. Check out: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#halting-execution and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Looking at your destroy method, if you checked the location count by @organization.locations.size (or .count) and moved the check up before loading the location, I think you might be able to save a database call. In other words, only do the specific location find if @organization.locations.count > 1. Otherwise, go straight to the error/redirect. Do you think that would work? [I may not have thought it through sufficiently.]